# Transform Soap to jsonx with xslt array issue

Tags: arrays, xml, xslt, soap

I'm learning xslt and I need your help. I have to do the transformation of a Soap message to Jsonx, the problem is that in the field "body" I need all the children are of type array, except the last child which must be of type object, I have the following entry code

```
<NS1:Envelope xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <NS1:Body>
      <NS2:Consulta xmlns:NS2="http://ejemplo.com/servicios">
         <header>
            <fechaHora>201612021719232416</fechaHora>
            <idioma>es_EC</idioma>
            <ip>192.168.1.23</ip>
         </header>
         <body>
            <productos>
               <tarjetas>
                  <tarjeta>
                     <numerotarjeta>123456789</numerotarjeta>
                     <tipo>MASTERCARD GOLD STN</tipo>
                     <moneda>USD</moneda>
                     <valorPagar>300</valorPagar>
                  </tarjeta>
                  <tarjeta>
                     <numerotarjeta>123456987</numerotarjeta>
                     <tipo>MASTERCARD GOLD STN</tipo>
                     <moneda>USD</moneda>
                     <valorPagar>15</valorPagar>
                  </tarjeta>
               </tarjetas>
               <libros>
                  <libro>
                     <id>123456789</id>
                     <nombre>Libro 1</nombre>
                  </libro>
               </libros>
               <revistas>
                  <revista>
                     <id>12</id>
                     <nombre>revista 1</nombre>
                  </revista>
                  <revista>
                     <id>122</id>
                     <nombre>revista 2</nombre>
                  </revista>
               </revistas>
            </productos>
         </body>
         <error>
            <error1>0</error1>
            <mensaje>OK</mensaje>
         </error>
      </NS2:Consulta>
   </NS1:Body>
</NS1:Envelope>
```

I am using the following xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- Array -->
    <xsl:template match="*[*[2]][name(*[1])=name(*[2])]">
        <json:object name="{name()}">
            <json:array name="{name(*[1])}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </json:array>
        </json:object>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Array member -->
    <xsl:template match="*[parent::*[ name(*[1])=name(*[2]) ]] | /">
        <json:object>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </json:object>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Object -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <json:object name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </json:object>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Object Body -->
    <xsl:template match="body[not(body)]">
        <json:array name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </json:array>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- String -->
    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <json:string name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </json:string>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

By applying the xslt I have the following result, in which I have a problem with the book tag, since it is an array that contains an element, but it converts it to an object, but it needs to be received as an array

```
<json:object xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
   <json:object name="NS1:Envelope">
      <json:object name="NS1:Body">
         <json:object name="NS2:Consulta">
            <json:object name="header">
               <json:string name="fechaHora">201612021719232416</json:string>
               <json:string name="idioma">es_EC</json:string>
               <json:string name="ip">192.168.1.23</json:string>
            </json:object>
            <json:array name="body">
               <json:object name="productos">
                  <json:object name="tarjetas">
                     <json:array name="tarjeta">
                        <json:object>
                           <json:string name="numerotarjeta">123456789</json:string>
                           <json:string name="tipo">MASTERCARD GOLD STN</json:string>
                           <json:string name="moneda">USD</json:string>
                           <json:string name="valorPagar">300</json:string>
                        </json:object>
                        <json:object>
                           <json:string name="numerotarjeta">123456987</json:string>
                           <json:string name="tipo">MASTERCARD GOLD STN</json:string>
                           <json:string name="moneda">USD</json:string>
                           <json:string name="valorPagar">15</json:string>
                        </json:object>
                     </json:array>
                  </json:object>
                  <json:object name="libros">
                     <json:object name="libro">
                        <json:string name="id">123456789</json:string>
                        <json:string name="nombre">Libro 1</json:string>
                     </json:object>
                  </json:object>
                  <json:object name="revistas">
                     <json:array name="revista">
                        <json:object>
                           <json:string name="id">12</json:string>
                           <json:string name="nombre">revista 1</json:string>
                        </json:object>
                        <json:object>
                           <json:string name="id">122</json:string>
                           <json:string name="nombre">revista 2</json:string>
                        </json:object>
                     </json:array>
                  </json:object>
               </json:object>
            </json:array>
            <json:object name="error">
               <json:string name="error1">0</json:string>
               <json:string name="mensaje">OK</json:string>
            </json:object>
         </json:object>
      </json:object>
   </json:object>
</json:object>
```

But should receive the following, since anywhere, book, magazine can come a single element and also transform it as an object but is an array of an element.

```
<json:object name="libros">
    <json:array name="libro">
       <json:string name="id">123456789</json:string>
       <json:string name="nombre">Libro 1</json:string>
    </json:array>
</json:object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the name of the elements (e.g. `libros`,`libro`) when writing the XSLT? In that case you could simply name them in the templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- Array -->
    <xsl:template match="*[*[2]][name(*[1])=name(*[2])] | libros[libro]">
        <json:object name="{name()}">
            <json:array name="{name(*[1])}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </json:array>
        </json:object>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Array member -->
    <xsl:template match="*[parent::*[ name(*[1])=name(*[2]) ]] | / | libro">
        <json:object>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </json:object>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Object -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <json:object name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </json:object>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Object Body -->
    <xsl:template match="body[not(body)]">
        <json:array name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </json:array>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- String -->
    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <json:string name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </json:string>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.net/ncntCSX outputs

```
              <json:object name="libros">
                 <json:array name="libro">
                    <json:object>
                       <json:string name="id">123456789</json:string>
                       <json:string name="nombre">Libro 1</json:string>
                    </json:object>
                 </json:array>
              </json:object>
```

Here is a suggestion trying to use a generic approach based on the nesting level (e.g. body descendants having a grand child element become arrays, their children array members):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- Array -->
    <xsl:template match="*[*[2]][name(*[1])=name(*[2])] | body//*[*/*]">
        <json:object name="{name()}">
            <json:array name="{name(*[1])}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </json:array>
        </json:object>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Array member -->
    <xsl:template match="*[parent::*[ name(*[1])=name(*[2]) ]] | / | body//*[*[not(*)]]">
        <json:object>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </json:object>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Object -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <json:object name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </json:object>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Object Body -->
    <xsl:template match="body[not(body)]">
        <json:array name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </json:array>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- String -->
    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <json:string name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </json:string>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/ncntCSX/1, creates the output

```
                 <json:object name="libros">
                    <json:array name="libro">
                       <json:object>
                          <json:string name="id">123456789</json:string>
                          <json:string name="nombre">Libro 1</json:string>
                       </json:object>
                    </json:array>
                 </json:object>
```

for the `libros` without mentioning that element name in the XSLT code.

Comment: The problem is that I do not always have the tag libros, there may be other types of items such as periodicos, revistas and others, so I would like to make it dynamic without being tied to a field name. Also I need that applied only to the elements inside body

Comment: Well, how can we decide which elements you want convert to an array and which not? You haven't explained that, instead only shown an XSLT that does not what you want. It is easy to match e.g. `body//*` to only match elements inside of a or the `body` element but so far you have not explained the criteria for the element to array or element to object transformation.

Comment: @Kalin666, I have added a second sample, trying to guess what you might want.